# web part search not displaying any results (Sharepoint online)

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-query-web-part

I created Contents query search for  my tasks across all the subsites. I can see results when I test it but nothing shows on the site page.

Could anyone help please -I searched all the forums but nothing seems to help?

I have sharepoint online

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Which web part did you add for search? Content query web part or Content search web part?

You could check if you have clicked the “OK” in the web part after editing the web part.

Then check if you have clicked “save” in the ribbon in the page.

And you also could create a new page and add the web part for search to check if the same issue will occur.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your reply. I followed this instructions: http://www.kalmstrom.com/Tips/SPSearch-My-Open-Tasks.htm

I.e. it is content search type. As I said I can see the results in the query itself but on the site page it doesn't return any results